# Convert coloured book scan pdf to 1 bit black and white

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, scanner, pdf-reader, scanning

I have a high dpi book scan which is very slow to read, probably owing to the fact that it has all gradation and colourful goodness of the pages and text. I want to get rid of everything extra and basically, make it into a 1 bit black & white format, in hopes of making it faster. I see a lot of old *free* books online that have this format, and they run fast enough.

How can I do it, preferably with just Adobe Acrobat Pro and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Acrobat Pro, choose:

**STEP 1**

- File -> Export to -> Image -> png
- In the "Save as" dialogue which opens, open the "Settings..."
- set Colorspace to Monochrome. You might have to experiment with Resolution in order to optimize between size and readability.
- Click OK to close settings. Choose an empty folder and click "Save". This will save each page as a separate image.

**STEP 2**

- Then, go to File -> Create -> Combine files into a single pdf
- Click "Add Files", and choose all the images you've saved in the previous step.
- On the next screen, you might want to adjust the settings. Then click "Combine"
- Save the created pdf. Finished.

**SIDE NOTE**
You might also want to consider to do an [OCR Text recognition](https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/ocr-software-convert-pdf-to-text.html), but it usually needs extensive correction of the result.